# How to change xlab and ylab in diagnostics function in R BAS package

Tags: r, plot, label, bayesian, diagnostics

For this function R:  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BAS/versions/1.4.7/topics/diagnostics, From BAS v1.4.7 by Merlise Clyde:

I have the previous plot that specified another xlab and lab.

Then when I call this specific diagnostics function, which outputs a plot, I cannot change specify/change the xlab and ylab in the "plot" function embedded within this diagnostics() function From BAS.

How to change xlab and ylab in diagnostics function in R BAS package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the argument `ann=F` of the default `plot()` to remove annotations first and then call `title()`. 
I built on the example available in the documentation (see the url you provided):

```
library(MASS)
library(BAS)
data(UScrime)
UScrime[,-2] = log(UScrime[,-2])
crime.ZS =  bas.lm(y ~ .,
                   data=UScrime,
                   prior="ZS-null",
                   modelprior=uniform(),
                   method = "MCMC",
                   MCMC.iter = 1000)   # short run for the example
diagnostics(crime.ZS, ann=F)
title(xlab= "new_xlab", ylab= "new_ylab")
```

Comment: Yes, Bravo! Your Answer works perfectly.   I Google the whole Internet and failed, and you've got it!

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean more thanks at all... I mean acceptance in the SO sense https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer! Anyway, I am happy it worked for you!